# Do not Show MPNowPlayingInfoCenter while play video, and show it when play audio

Tags: ios, xamarin, media-player

I want make an apps that play audio and video. I want the audio can play on background mode, so I add the MediaPlayerInfo. While I do not want the video played on background mode. So I do not need the MediaPlayerInfo while play video.

But somehow the MediaPlayerInfo still shown in notification bar while I play the video, although I didn't set it.
I already try to set is as "null" but it didn't change the behavior.

Anyone can help me to make the MediaPlayerInfo shown while play audio in background mode, but did not shown while play video (background & foreground mode)?

(Update) this is snippet of my code:

```
    private MPRemoteCommandCenter m_commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.Shared;
    private string m_currentAudioTitle = "";
    private MPNowPlayingInfo _currentFileInfo;
    NSObject _playCommandTarget;
    NSObject _pauseCommandTarget;
    NSObject _skipBackwardCommandTarget;
    NSObject _skipForwardCommandTarget;

public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        m_observerList.Add(NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(aName: UIApplication.DidEnterBackgroundNotification, notify: HandleDidEnterBackgroundNotification));
        m_observerList.Add(NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(aName: UIApplication.WillEnterForegroundNotification, notify: HandleWillEnterForegroundNotification));
    }


public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);

        foreach (NSObject _observer in m_observerList)
        {
            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(_observer);
        }
    }

private void HandleWillEnterForegroundNotification(NSNotification obj)
    {
        RemoveRemoteTransportControl();
        RemoveNowPlaying();
    }

private void HandleDidEnterBackgroundNotification(NSNotification obj)
    {
        SetupRemoteTransportControl();
        SetupNowPlaying("Test Asset Name");
    }

 public void SetupRemoteTransportControl()
    {
        m_commandCenter.SkipBackwardCommand.Enabled = true;
        m_commandCenter.SkipForwardCommand.Enabled = true;

        _playCommandTarget = m_commandCenter.PlayCommand.AddTarget(PlayAudioBackground);
        _pauseCommandTarget = m_commandCenter.PauseCommand.AddTarget(PauseAudioBackground);
        _skipBackwardCommandTarget = m_commandCenter.SkipBackwardCommand.AddTarget(SkipBackwardBackground);
        _skipForwardCommandTarget = m_commandCenter.SkipForwardCommand.AddTarget(SkipForwardBackground);
    }

    public void RemoveRemoteTransportControl()
    {
        m_commandCenter.SkipBackwardCommand.Enabled = false;
        m_commandCenter.SkipForwardCommand.Enabled = false;
        m_commandCenter.PlayCommand.RemoveTarget(_playCommandTarget);
        m_commandCenter.PauseCommand.RemoveTarget(_pauseCommandTarget);
        m_commandCenter.SkipBackwardCommand.RemoveTarget(_skipBackwardCommandTarget);
        m_commandCenter.SkipForwardCommand.RemoveTarget(_skipForwardCommandTarget);
        m_commandCenter.Dispose();
    }

 public void SetupNowPlaying(string aAssetTitle = null)
    {
        _currentFileInfo = new MPNowPlayingInfo();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(aAssetTitle))
        {
            m_currentAudioTitle = aAssetTitle;

        }
        Console.WriteLine("SetupNowPlaying: "+ m_currentAudioTitle);
        _currentFileInfo.Title = m_currentAudioTitle;
        _currentFileInfo.ElapsedPlaybackTime = apPlayer.CurrentTime.Seconds;
        _currentFileInfo.PlaybackDuration = m_audioAsset.Duration.Seconds;
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.DefaultCenter.NowPlaying = _currentFileInfo;
    }

public void RemoveNowPlaying()
    {
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.DefaultCenter.NowPlaying = _currentFileInfo;
    }
```

Comment: Hi , you need to share code in question , then we will check where problem is . By the way , you can have a try with using the AVPlayer to play audio .https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/xamarin-ios-audio-player-notification

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT  already update  my question, add snippet of my code.

Comment: Thanks , I will check it .If point will share here.